# Count duplicate entries SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, duplicate, count

I need a little help please.

I'm using SharePoint 2013, with no SharePoint designer (disabled by the administrator).

I have a list, in which we have duplicated entries in a column named Title. I need to count those duplicates so I can apply a filter and view just those who have 3 or more occurrences. Is it possible?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

1. Create a standard view containing [Title] column, Group by [Title], and Totals [Count] on [Title]
2. Then filter the view by selecting [Title]s in the headers of the view for which count >=3

See the screenshots below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how many occurrences I have of a given Title, so I can't apply a filter as you did.